# InFlateException occures in some android device

Tags: java, kotlin, inflate-exception

I have one app in the Play Store and which is Arabic to Bangla dictionary. I have noticed for some devices it is throwing an InFlateException in a function which I have given below. The app is works well on some devices but some specific devices crash due to this exception. The exception showing on the below function. My question is why this type of exception occurs and what is the possible solution for this?

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_acitvity)

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
//        realm.beginTransaction()
//        realm.delete(Users::class.java)
//        realm.commitTransaction()
        if(intent.hasExtra("message")) {
            val msg = intent.getStringExtra("message")
            reg_success_msg.text = msg
            reg_success_msg.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorSuccess)
            reg_success_msg.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        handle_login.setOnClickListener {
            login_progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            login_alert_area.visibility = View.GONE
            login_alert.text = ""
            closeKeyboard(ET_activation_code)
            val email = ET_email.text.toString().trim()
            password = ET_password.text.toString().trim()
            val transaction_id = ET_activation_code.text.toString().trim()
            if(email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                login_alert.text = "সব ঘর পূরণ করতে হবে"
                login_alert_area.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                login_progress.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                if(checkNetworkConnection()) {
                    var newUser = User(
                        email = email,
                        password = password,
                        transaction_id = transaction_id
                    )

                    val userService: UserService = ServiceBuilder.buildService(UserService::class.java)
                    val requestCall: Call<User> = userService.login(newUser)

                    requestCall.enqueue(object : Callback<User>{
                        override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            login_progress.visibility = View.GONE
                        }

                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
                            val code = response.code()
                            val body = response.body()
                            if(code == 200) {
                                addUserToLocalDb(body)
                                login_progress.visibility = View.GONE
                                login_alert_area.visibility = View.GONE
                                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(intent)
                                finish()
                            } else if(code == 201) {
                                login_alert.text = body!!.error.toString()
                                login_alert_area.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                login_progress.visibility = View.GONE
                            }
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    login_alert.text = "ইউজার পাওয়া যায় নি। ইন্টারনেট চালু করে চেষ্টা করুন"
                    login_alert_area.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    login_progress.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

        btn_close_error.setOnClickListener {
            login_alert.text = ""
            login_alert_area.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        login_alert_area.setOnClickListener {
            login_alert.text = ""
            login_alert_area.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        btn_registration.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, RegistrationActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        forget_pass_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ForgetPasswordActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_how_to_activate.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, HowToActivateActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_how_to_use.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, HowToUseActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_feature.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, FeatureActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_owner.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, OwnerActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_contact.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ContactActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        btn_copyright.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CopyrightActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

[image: Here is my crash report]

Comment: Do any of the answers to [this question](/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class) apply?

Comment: Can you tap on one of those and see the stacktrace? That should tell you where the error is in the XML file. It's *possible* that you're referring to a resource that's missing - that can happen if you're using the Android App Bundle format, which generates an APK customised for the device that's installing an app from the Play Store. All the resources it doesn't need (like drawables for other densities) get stripped out, which causes a problem if that APK gets shared and installed on a device with a different config